# How to send get request with multiple same params in axios

Tags: parameters, get, axios

I want to put multiple same key in params and send `GET` request in axios to server.

In backend, it requires `http://example.com/?id=absdbasbd&id=basdbasb&id=a11`.

I am using axios and it uses JS object to send the request params. And obviously such object can't have multiple fields with the same key.

How to put multiple same key in params?

Comment: In PHP it's done with `id[]` instead of `id` to imply that `id` is an array with multiple elements. I know nothing about axios but I suppose it's worth a try.

Comment: did u solved it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can send params like this:

```
  var params = {
  not: ['github', 'twitter'],
  limit: limit
}
return axios.get('/api_new', {
    params: params
  })
```

axios will build url like this `/api_new?not[]=github&not[]=twitter&limit=10`

axios auto add `[]` at the end of the list type params name

see more in this issues https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/604